# Substitute From Implicit `show` Call

Tags: r, r-s4, substitution

I need to recover the expression implicitly used to invoke a call to `show` from within a `show` method, but this only works with an explicit show call:

```
> setClass("test", representation(a="character"))
> setMethod("show", "test", function(object) cat(deparse(substitute(object))))
[1] "show"
> show(new("test"))    # explicit call: as expected
new("test")
> new("test")          # implicit: not so much...
<S4 object of class structure("test", package = ".GlobalEnv")>
```

There seems to be a similar issue with print and S3 objects, but I'm more interested in the S4 version here.  Any way to work around this?  I looked at the call stack with `sys.calls` but there was no call recorded with the original expression which suggests to me this may be too low level to be resolved easily.

Comment: why do you need to recover calls for implicit print ? This is only in interactive sessions. Here it' s the R console that prints your object.

Comment: I'm building an interactive interface that involves users manipulating S4 objects interactively.

Comment: ok, but that still does not really answer the question: is there  console from which you want to recover implicit calls to show ?

Comment: I'm doing this from RStudio, but ideally would like the solution to work on any console so that the package that incorporates this approach is not UI dependent.

Answer (score 0):

```
> showDefault
function (object, oldMethods = TRUE) 
{
    clDef <- getClass(cl <- class(object), .Force = TRUE)
    cl <- classLabel(cl)
    if (!is.null(clDef) && isS4(object) && is.na(match(clDef@className, 
        .BasicClasses))) {
        cat("An object of class ", cl, "\n", sep = "")
        slots <- slotNames(clDef)
        dataSlot <- .dataSlot(slots)
        if (length(dataSlot) > 0) {
            dataPart <- slot(object, dataSlot)
            show(dataPart)
            slots <- slots[is.na(match(slots, dataSlot))]
        }
        else if (length(slots) == 0L) 
            show(unclass(object))
        for (what in slots) {
            if (identical(what, ".Data")) 
                next
            cat("Slot \"", what, "\":\n", sep = "")
            print(slot(object, what))
            cat("\n")
        }
    }
    else print(object, useS4 = FALSE)
    invisible()
}
<bytecode: 0x11c228000>
<environment: namespace:methods>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question.  I can call `showDefault` on my S4 object, sure, but the whole point is that I want to capture the expression the implicit show/print used (i.e. what someone typed at the prompt) from the show/print method.  Maybe there is something above here that does this, but it's not obvious to me.